# Adding watchOS complications in Xcode 14 results in CoreData API Misuse error

Tags: xcode, core-data, watchos, apple-watch-complication

In Xcode 14 beta 6, when I add complication placeholders in the watchOS Assets.xcassets, it gives me the CoreData API Misuse error as I add them. Does anyone here have any idea on how to resolve the CoreData API Misuse error?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I have exact this error!! did you find any solution?

Comment: Same issue here...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your complications assets have their Scale set to Single Size and not Individual Scales.

I wrote about it [here](https://sowenjub.me/writes/single-size-icons-solving-command-compileassetcatalog-failed-with-a-nonzero-exit-code/).